# TypeScript discriminated unions over two properties instead of one?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to do discriminated unions in TypeScript over **two properties** instead of one? [Here is a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgTgewO4GcJwEoQLYONAXigG8AoKCqOHPCALimDgFcJzKAzBBBlJgSwB2Ac1IBfUqVCRYiVOgAyCAMYBDADZQiZSlABGquLwEjxk6dAByCACYQsufFpLsK1R-UYs2ugwC9jOCFRCSlwK1sIAGF1fghBYCU1TW1XKGVY+OAGJlY0vWDA4LMwmWs7GLiEh1pnHUo9bmwi01CLKHKIABVw506apwAfDsjKrKSNKGHOseqafHNe+GQ0OB6ZImX5THnoYa3VifVJDmZBZWB+BEF064A3dGBOgAohMGZskbt1iABKF10ymuKAQ6ggADp1AhhK9BO9gL8SqdzpdrrdBA84MADuhYfCGDi1uF-vUKEDBCCwZDoXiPojQuTMU9Is9SVRdjlvAAafKqAJQADkXAQAvEiNIjMeLzZ7lonNYPN8TQYQu4orEvyAA):

```
type BrowserRemote = {
    remote: true
    foo: string
}

type BrowserLocal = {
    bar: string
}

type NodeRemote = {
    remote: true
    baz: string
}

type NodeClientLocal = {
    client: true
    bing: string
}

type NodeClientRemote = {
    boom: string
}

type NodeType = NodeRemote | NodeClientLocal | NodeClientRemote

type BrowserType = BrowserRemote | BrowserLocal

function convertNode(input: NodeType) {
    console.log(input)
}

function convertBrowser(input: BrowserType) {
    console.log(input)
}

convertNode({
    remote: true,
    baz: 'foo'
})

convertNode({
    remote: true,
    boom: 'foo'
})
```

Basically, I have two functions `convertNode` and `convertBrowser`, one for Node.js and one for the browser. The Node.js function can take 3 input styles depending on if it's making a `remote` request (connecting to a REST API internally), or making a local request (remote is undefined). The local request can be either coming from a `client` or not coming from a client (client is undefined). The browser can be either `remote` or not remote, so it's a simpler version than Node.js. So let's focus on Node.js.

The "discriminated union" property really is a combination of 2 properties:

- `remote: true, client: undefined | false`
- `remote: undefined | false, client: true`
- `remote: undefined | false, client: undefined | false`

But I would like to not have to pass in `client: undefined` or `remote: undefined` into my function calls. Likewise, I would like the API to stay like this, with 2 properties instead of 1 property. 1 property might look like this:

- `source: 'remote'`
- `source: 'local:client'`
- `source: 'local'`

I may go with that approach if absolutely necessary, but I wanted to see if this was possible somehow to do discriminated unions on the 2 properties, to get that TypeScript playground to work. Is it possible? If not, why not? If so, how could you get it to work?

Note: Each permutation will have some shared properties and some unique properties. So remote/local:client/local will each have some similar properties, and some different properties. In addition, they might have a property named the same thing, but a different type, like this:

```
type NodeLocalClient = {
  client: true
  file: ArrayBuffer
}

type NodeLocal = {
  file: string
}
```

Granted, I could really try to have the props of different types have different names, but it may not always be desirable to try and enforce that.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Is there a use case you're trying to test here? Or a problem you ran into when trying it that's causing you to ask the question? Your code example doesn't have any errors or clearly indicate some problem you're having.  Could you change it to be a [mre] that demonstrates some motivation for the question?  Maybe I'm completely missing some actual problem that you have?

Comment: The error is the fact there is _no error_ in the second `convertNode` call.

Comment: ① Please [edit] to make that obvious to someone reading the question; it should jump out at us. ② Even a single-discriminant discriminated union needs to have the property mentioned in each type; if you want to say "false or undefined" then do it explicitly [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mLAzZW). But this has little to do with having two discriminants and everything to do with actually discriminating the union. Maybe you should [edit] the question to be about a single discriminant and distinguishing `true` from "missing"?